# Proof that each well ordered set is similar to a unique ordinal number (according to Halmos)

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, ordinals

I'm trying to follow the proof that is given in the "Naive Set Theory" by Halmos that each well ordered set is similar to a unique ordinal number (which Halmos calls the Counting Theorem):

> **Counting Theorem**. Each well ordered set is similar to a unique ordinal number.
>
> Since for ordinal numbers similarity is the same as equality, uniqueness is obvious. Suppose now that $X$ is a well ordered set and suppose that an element $a$ of $X$ is such that the initial segment determined by each predecessor of $a$ is similar to some (necessarily unique) ordinal number. If $S(x, \alpha)$ is the sentence that says "$\alpha$ is an ordinal number and $s(x)$
> is similar to $\alpha$", then, for each $x$ in $s(a)$, the set $\{\alpha: S(x, \alpha)\}$ can be formed; in fact, that set is a singleton. The axiom of substitution implies the existence of a set consisting exactly of the ordinal numbers similar to the initial segments determined by the predecessors of $a$. It follows, whether $a$ is the immediate successor of one of its predecessors or the supremum of them all, that $s(a)$ is similar to an ordinal number. This argument prepares the way for an application of the prinicple of transfinite induction; the conclusion is that each initial segment in $X$ is similar to some ordinal number. This fact, in turn, justifies another application of the axiom of substitution, just like the one made above; the final conclusion is, as desired, that $X$ is similar to some ordinal number.

I cannot understand what is the justification of the step: "It follows, whether $a$ is the immediate successor of one of its predecessors or the supremum of them all, that $s(a)$ is similar to an ordinal number."

I understand the construction of the set $\{\alpha: S(x, \alpha)\}$, but I only see that each element of that set is an ordinal number which is similar to some of the initial segments of $s(a)$. I also see that they are ordered by continuation (but so is any set of ordered numbers). From the step that puzzles me, I expect that the said set has to be an ordinal number, or at least to be similar to an ordinal number, but I can't see how this can be shown (or how this can be obvious).

PS.
As far as I know, some of the terms that Halmos uses have modern equivalents:
similar = order-isomorphic
Axiom of Substitution = Axiom of Replacement

Halmos also has proven a fact hat every set of ordinal numbers has a supremum in the text just before that. This might be helpful, as $\{\alpha: S(x, \alpha)\}$ is definitely a set of ordinal numbers. So it must have a supremum, but what is it to do next, I don't understand.

**UPDATE**

After asking the question I think I pinpointed the part which is difficult to me.

Halmos asserts the fact that $s(a)$ is similar to an ordered number whether $a$ is the immediate successor of one of its predecessors, or the supremum of them.

In case $a$ is the immediate successor, it's easy to see that $s(a)$ is similar to some ordered number. There should be some $b \in s(a)$ such that $a$ is the immediate successor of $b$. Then $s(b)$ is similar to some ordinal number, say $\beta$ and $s(a)$ is similar to $\beta^+$. But I don't understand how to show the same if $a$ is the supremum of $s(a)$.

Comment: In case $a$ is the supremum that has no immediate predecessor, $s(a)$ will be the union of all $s(x)$ where $x \in s(a)$, form the union $A$ of all ordinal numbers $\alpha$ similar to each $s(x)$,  $A$ is by definition an ordinal number itself, with the $\alpha$’s being its initial segments. By comparability theorem we have $s(a) \cong A$.

Answer (score 2):

Been reading this book to fill some knowledge gaps on set theory, so here's my solution (taking uniqueness of ordinal equivalence for granted):

*Claim:* Suppose that $X$ is a well-ordered set such that every initial segment of $X$ is similar to an ordinal number. Then $X$ is itself similar to an ordinal number.

*Proof:* For any $x \in X$, we know that there exists an ordinal number similar to $x$ by hypothesis; the singleton set containing this ordinal is then precisely the set $\{ \alpha : \alpha \text{ is an ordinal and } \alpha \cong s(x) \}$ by uniqueness of ordinal similarity. By the axiom of substitution, there exists a function $F$ with domain $X$ such that $F(x)$ is the aforementioned set for each $x \in X$. Since each element $F(x)$ is a (non-empty) singleton set, we can form the unique function $f$ of domain $X$ satisfying $F(x) = \{ f(x) \}$ (i.e. $f$ removes the curly braces from the result of $F$). The result is a function $f$ with the property that, for all $x \in X$, $f(x)$ is an ordinal and $f(x) \cong s(x)$.

Denote by $S$ the range of $f$. We claim that $S$ is an ordinal. As established, $S$ is a set of ordinals, so it is well ordered under set inclusion/membership. Suppose now that $\alpha \in S$. The initial segment of $\alpha$ in $S$ is included in $\alpha$ by definition; it remains to be shown that every element of $\alpha$ is included in $S$ (and therefore also in its initial segment). Suppose $\beta \in \alpha$. Then if $\alpha$ is the image of $x \in X$, it is similar to $s(x)$, say through the similarity $\varphi$. Now it is easy to show that $\varphi$ restricts over the initial segment of $\beta$ in $\alpha$ to a similarity. Noting that $\varphi(s(\beta)) = s(\varphi(\beta))$ as a consequence of the fact that $\varphi$ is a similarity, $\left.\varphi\right|_{s(\beta)}$ is a similarity between $s(\beta) = \beta$ (taking $\beta \in \alpha$, an ordinal) and $s(\varphi(\beta))$. Since $\varphi(\beta) \in s(x) \subseteq X$, we have $\beta \in S$ as desired.

Now the sets $X$ and $S$ are each well-ordered, and so there are three cases. If they are similar, we are done. If $X$ is similar to an initial segment of $S$, then since an initial segment of an ordinal is again an ordinal, we are done. Finally, suppose $S$ is similar to an initial segment $s(x)$ of $X$. We then have that $s(x)$ is similar to the ordinals $f(x)$ and $S$, so that $f(x) \cong S \implies f(x) = S$. However, $f$ has range $S$, so $f(x) \in S \implies f(x) \in f(x) \implies f(x) < f(x)$, a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Now the proof in the book goes as follows:

> Since for the ordinal numbers similarity is the same as equality, uniqueness is obvious. Suppose now that $X$ is a well ordered set and suppose that an element $a$ of $X$ is such that the initial segment determined by each predecessor of $a$ is similar to some (necessarily unique) ordinal number. By the claim, $s(a)$ itself is then similar to some ordinal number. Applying transfinite induction, all of the initial segments of $X$ are similar to some ordinal number. Applying the claim now to $X$, $X$ itself is similar to some ordinal number.

I still unfortunately can not answer what the hell the author intended with the phrase "whether $a$ is the immediate successor of one of its predecessors or the supremum of them all, that $s(a)$ is similar to an ordinal number."

Comment: This may be just a nitpick but anyway I think that you are forced to conclude that $X \cong S$ because if $X$ is similar to an initial segment of $S$, say the element $\xi = f(x)$, then, by the definition of $f$, $X$ would be similar to $s(x)$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the following development, which is done in ZF minus the axioms of Infinity and Foundation (a.k.a. Regularity):

(1). Well-Orders. For a well-order $<$ on a set $A$ we define an initial segment of $A$ as  $\{b\in A: b<a\}$ for some (any) $a\in A.$ And write $pred_< a=\{b\in A: b<a\}.$ ("pred" for predecessors).

(1.1). The only isomorphism of a well-order to itself is the identity.

(1.2). There is at most one isomorphism from one well-order to another.

(1.3) A well-order is not isomorphic to an initial segment of itself.

(1.4). Distinct initial segments are not isomorphic to each other.

(1.5). The Main Theorem. Trichotomy.

For any well-orders $A, B$ exactly one of the following is true:

(i). $A$ is isomorphic to $B.$

(ii). $A$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $B.$

(iii). $B$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $A.$

Proof of (1.5): Let $<_A, <_B$ be the well-ordering relations on $A, B$ respectively. Let $A^*$ be the set of those $a\in  A$ for which there is an isomorphism $f_a:pred_{<_A}\to pred_{<_B}b$ for some $b\in B.$

(i'). By (1.3), $b$ is unique, and by that and (1.2), $f_a$ is unique. So let $g(a)=b$ (By Replacement applied to $A^*$). So for $a\in A^*,$ we have $f_a:pred_{<_A}\to pred_{<_B}g(a).$

(ii'). Let $a\in A^*$ and $a'<_A a.$ The restriction of $f_a$ to $pred_{<_A}a'$ is an isomorphism to an initial segment $pred_{<_B}b'$ of $B,$ so $a'\in A^*.$  Also, by  (i') and (1.3) and (1.2) we have $b'=g(a')$ and the restriction of $f_a$ to $pred_{<_A}a'$ is $f_{a'}.$ It should be clear that $g(a')<_B g(a).$

Furthermore, if $b''<_B g(a)$ then because $f_a$ is an isomorphism, the set $(f_a)^{-1}pred_{<_B}b''$ is equal  to $pred_{<_A}a''$ for some $a''\le_A a,$ so $b''=g(a'').$

So $A^*$ is either $A$ or an initial segment of $A,$ and the set $G=\{g(a):a\in A^*\}$ is either $B$ or is an initial segment of $B,$ and $g:A^*\to G$ is an isomorphism.

(iii'). (Case One). If $A^*=A$ then (i) or (ii) of the Theorem is true,but not both, by (1.3). And (iii) cannot be true because if $h$ was an isomorphism of $B$ to an initial segment of $A$ then $(h|_G)\circ g$ would be an isomorphism from $A$ to an initial segment of $A,$ contrary to (1.3).

(iv'). (Case Two). If  $A^*=pred_{<_A}\alpha$ then $G=B.$ Otherwise, if $G=pred_{<_B}\beta,$ then $g:pred_{<_A}\alpha\to pred_{<_B}\beta$ is an isomorphism. But then the definition of $A^*$ implies $\alpha \in A^*,$ which is absurd because $A^*=pred_{<_A}\alpha.$

So if $A^*$ is an initial segment of $A$ then (iii) of the Theorem is true, and by applications of (1.3), (i) and (ii) are false.

(2). Ordinals. Let $<_A$ be a well-order on $A .$ To prove $A$ is isomorphic to an ordinal:

Case I: If there exists ordinal $B$ such that (i) holds, we are done.

Case II: If there exits ordinal $B$ such that (ii) holds, then since an initial segment of an ordinal is also an ordinal, we are done.

Case III. If cases I and II never hold then (iii) holds for every $B\in On$ (every ordinal $B$). Now for any $a\in A$  the set $pred_{<_A}a$ is isomorphic to at most one $B\in On$ by (1.3) because if $B,B'$ are distinct ordinals then one of them is an initial segmnt of the other. So for $a\in A$ let $h(a)=B$ if $pred_{<_A}a$ is isomorphic to $B\in On,$ and $h(a)=\emptyset$ otherwise. By Replacement the set $\{h(a):a\in A\}=On$ exists, but this is impossible. So Case I or Case II must apply and we are done.

(3).Remarks.

(3a). Lemmas (1.1),(1.2), (1.3) and (1.4) are easy to prove by contradiction. E.g. for (1.1) suppose $f:A\to A$ is an isomorphism and $a_0$ is the least $a\in A$ such that $f(a)\ne a.$ And we use (1.1) to prove (1.2). For (1.3) suppose $f:A\to pred_<a$ is an isomorphism . Then $f(a)<a,$ so consider the least $\alpha \in A$ such that $f(\alpha)\ne \alpha$.....Let me know if you need help with them.

(3b). Remember that in the language of Set Theory in use here, $B\in On$ does not assert there exists a set $On$. It is an abbreviation for "$\forall b\in B\,(b\subset B),$ and $B$ is well-ordered by $\in$".

Comment: Perhaps it would be smoother if, before proving (1.5), I had shown  that  at $most $ one of (i),(ii),(iii) can be true

Comment: In the book, 'Naive Set Theory', a well-ordered set has a non-strict well-ordering. Does it not matter whether they have strict well-orderings or non-strict well-orderings?

Comment: @user682705 . No......By "strict", I assume you mean $a<b\implies a\ne b.$ Suppose $\le$ is a binary relation on $A$ such that for every non-empty $B\subseteq $ there is a $unique$ $b\in B$ such that $b\le c$ for all $c\in B$ such that $c\ne b.$ Now define $a<b\iff (a\le b \land a\ne b).$ Then $<$ is a strict well-order.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give my attempt at completing the proof even though it is in many respects similar to the one given by @Kevin Osborn.

---

> Let $(W,\leq)$ be a well-ordered set, then we claim that there exists a unique ordinal number $\alpha$ such that $W \cong \alpha$.

*Proof:* First of all notice that if a well-ordered set is similar to an ordinal number then this must be unique because similarity and equality are the same thing for ordinal numbers. Now, define
$$
S \equiv \{x \in W: \exists \alpha_x \text{ ordinal number}: s(x) \cong \alpha_x\}
$$
and suppose that $s(x) \subseteq S$. Let $s(y,\alpha)$ be the sentence "$y \in s(x)$, $\alpha$ is an ordinal number, $s(y) \cong \alpha$" so that  $\forall y \in s(x)$ we can construct the set $\{\alpha:S(y,\alpha)\}$ which is just $\{\alpha_y\}$ (a singleton by what we said before on uniqueness). The Axiom of Substitution then states that there exists a function $F$ with domain $s(x)$ such that $\forall y \in s(x), F(y) = \{\alpha_y\}$, therefore consider the set $\alpha_x \equiv \bigcup \text{ran}(F)$ which only consists of ordinal numbers and thus it is well-ordered by the relation of belonging. We claim that $\alpha_x$ is also an ordinal number. Indeed, fix an arbitrary element of $\alpha_x$, i.e. $\alpha_y$ for some $y \in s(x)$, then we just need to show that $\alpha_y \subseteq s(\alpha_y)$, since surely $s(\alpha_y) \subseteq \alpha_y$, where $s(\alpha_y)$ is the initial segment determined by $\alpha_y$ in $\alpha_x$. Suppose $\beta \in \alpha_y$ then, since $\beta = s(\beta)$ (initial segment in $\alpha_y$), $\beta$ is similar to an initial segment of $s(y)$ which is just an initial segment of $s(x)$ determined by some element $z$ so that $\beta \cong s(z)$ and thus $\beta \in \alpha_x$. Finally, $\alpha_x$ and $s(x)$ are both well-ordered, hence, by the Comparability Theorem for well-ordered sets, exactly one of the following three options must be true:

1. $s(x)$ is similar to an initial segment of $\alpha_x$
2. $\alpha_x$ is similar to an initial segment of $s(x)$
3. $s(x) \cong \alpha_x$

Clearly 1 and 2 can not hold for otherwise we would have that a well-ordered set is similar to one of its initial segments, therefore only 3 holds and it tells us that $s(x)$ is similar to an ordinal number. By transfinite induction we have shown that $\forall x \in W, x \in S$. Now we just need to repeat the exact procedure to show that $W$ is similar to an ordinal number: first we define the sentence $p(x,\alpha)$ as "$x \in W$, $\alpha$ is an ordinal number, $s(x) \cong \alpha$", then we apply the Axiom of Substitution using the previously proved result and finally the union of the range of the function thus obtained is the desired ordinal number. $\square$