# Question about a proof that any well-ordered set is isomorphic to a unique ordinal

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

I am studying a proof that every well-ordered set is isomorphic to a unique ordinal. However, I don't understand why $A = pred(\omega)$ (see yellow).

[image]
[image]

One direction is clear:

Let $x \in pred(\omega)$, then $x < \omega$. Now since $\omega$ is the least element of $W \setminus A$, $x \in A$.

Hint: $pred(x)$ is the set of predecessors of $x$.
[image]

In the [recording of the lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPj3-tWWZPE&list=PLuiPz6iU5SQ_3Gubdqa1JHBvM0GBFcIV0&index=25) (at 31:58) the professor argues that the other direction also follows from the fact that $\omega$ is the least element of $W \setminus A$, but I don't see how. Does the converse really follow from this fact alone?

The only thing I could come up with is the following:

Assume there exists $v \in A$ such that $v \not \in pred(\omega)$. Then $v \not \in pred(\omega)$ implies that $\omega<v$, and so $pred(\omega) \subsetneq pred(v)$. Since $v \in A$, there exists an ordinal $\alpha_v$ s.t. $(pred(v), <)$ is isomorphic to $(\alpha_v, \in_{\alpha_v})$ by the definition of $A$. Let $f$ be the order-isomorphism between those sets and consider its restriction to the set $pred(\omega)$:

$f \restriction_{pred(\omega)} \to f[pred(\omega)]$

Then $f \restriction_{pred(\omega)}$ is also an order isomorphism and $f[pred(\omega)]$ is a proper subset of an ordinal, and thus also an ordinal. But then $\omega \in A$ by the definition of $A$, which contradicts the definition of $\omega$.

This is basically a proof by contradiction within a proof by contradiction (to show that $A = W$), but **don't need** the fact that $\omega$ is **the least element** of $W \setminus A$ for this.

Could anyone please clarify the step in the proof? Also is my proof above correct?

Thank you very much!

Edit: My proof actually does not work since a proper subset of an ordinal is not necessarily an ordinal.

Comment: See my answer to this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309054/proof-that-each-well-ordered-set-is-similar-to-a-unique-ordinal-number-accordin/3311472#3311472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall some basic facts: For a partially ordered set $P$ and $x\in P$, you can more generally define $pred(x)=\{y\in P,\, y<x\}$. These subsets (I've seen them called initial segments) are preserved by order isomorphisms. In other words, if $f:P\to Q$ is some order isomorphism between posets, then $f(pred(x))=pred(f(x))$. Moreover, for ordinals $\alpha\in\beta$ ordered by membership, $pred(\alpha)=\alpha$.

Bearing all that in mind, let's go back to your problem. Using the given notation, notice now how if $v\in A$, then $pred(v)\subset A$. Indeed let $f:pred(v)\to\alpha$ be an isomorphism to an ordinal number, then for any $u\prec v$, $f(pred(u))=pred(f(u))=f(u)$ an ordinal. So the appropriate restriction of $f$ is indeed an isomorphism between $pred(u)$ and the ordinal $f(u)$. Therefore $u\in A$ and $pred(v)\subset A$.

This allows to fix your argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I understand the basic facts you've listed, but you should probably write that if $\alpha \in \beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals, then $pred(\alpha) = \alpha$. Otherwise, it is not clear what $pred(\alpha)$ should be. Of course, we can simply use $\beta = S(\alpha)$.

Comment: To prove the claim we then note that $u<v \implies u \in pred(v)$, and so $f(u) \in \alpha$. Therefore, $f(u)$ is an ordinal (since elements of ordinals are ordinals), and hence is the set of its predecessors in $\alpha$. This proves that $u \in A$ by the definition of $A$. In particular, $w \in A$, which is a contradiction. Did I understand your argument correctly?

Comment: When you have that $v\in A \Rightarrow pred(v)\subset A$, the argument only needs one  short step actually. If $w\prec v$ and $v\in A$ then $w\in pred(v)\subset A$ a contradiction. Notice how we don't need $f$ anymore. It's maybe more insightful if you go back to your proof and use only the 'basic facts' to fix it.

Comment: Ah never mind, I now see that's exactly what you did in your last comment.

Comment: Yes, exactly and your proof is also exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks again for steering me in the right direction.